# Flask request.files returns an empty ImmutableMultiDict([])

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I've seen many similar questions and yet none have the answer to my problem. I try to send a file through AJAX to my flask app and i only get an empty ImmutableMultiDict([]) with the flask request.files object what am i doing wrong?

Here is my form;

```
<form id="edit_form" action='' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input type='file' id='image_field' name="image">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="title_en">Title EN:</label>
        <input type="text" id="title_en" name="title_en">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="title_fr">Title FR:</label>
        <input type="text" id="title_fr" name="title_fr">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

my JS;

```
var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append("file", $("#edit_form #image_field")[0]);
console.log(form_data);
var id = document.querySelector("#edit_form").getAttribute("product_id");
form_data.append("id", id);
      $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/api/add_product_image',
          data: form_data,
          contentType: multipart/form-data,
          success: function(data) {
              console.log('Success!');
              // put up image in preview
          },
      });
```

and my python code;

```
@app.route('/api/add_product_image', methods=['POST'])
def add_product_image():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # retreive from form data
        print(request.form)
        try:
            id = request.form["id"]
            print(request.files)
            file = request.files.get("file")
            file.save("./static/imgs/"+id+".png")
            return {"status": "success"}
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return {"status": "error", "message": ""}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to append a file to your formdata object, you are appending the input control

```
form_data.append("file", $("#edit_form #image_field")[0].files[0]);
```

Also, to use FormData with jQuery.ajax you have to set contentType and processData to `false`

```
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/api/add_product_image',
      data: form_data,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(data) {
          console.log('Success!');
          // put up image in preview
      },
  });
```

Comment: then it gives me `'str' object has no attribute 'save'`. It's sending me the string of the file path on the client instead of a file.

Comment: Thanks now it works with your change, the other error was my content type without quote.